# Android Retrofit Dynamic Query Variable

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am currently using the Retrofit Library for android: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

```
interface MainApi {
@GET('/api/updateuser')
    fun updateUser(
            @Query("userId") userId: UserId,
            @Nullable @Query("programId") programId: ProgramId?): Observable<UserResponse>
}
```

But I am having an issue where I need to add a dynamic variable into the GET or POST such that `hobby_x = id`. So for example: `hobby_12=15` or  `hobby_35=100`.

How can I execute this in with the Retrofit Library?

Answer (score 0):

When you have "dynamic" queries (either an unknown set of query params or an unknown query key name), the easiest way to handle it is to use [the `@QueryMap` annotation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/QueryMap.html).

```
interface MainApi {

    @GET("/api/updateuser")
    fun updateUser(
            @Query("userId") userId: UserId,
            @Nullable @Query("programId") programId: ProgramId?,
            @QueryMap Map<String, String> hobbies
    ): Observable<UserResponse>
}
```

And then you could call it as:

```
val hobbies = mapOf("hobby_12" to "15")
service.updateUser("foo", null, hobbies)
```

or

```
val hobbies = mapOf("hobby_35" to "100")
service.updateUser("foo", null, hobbies)
```